# Why Android FrameMetrics.DEADLINE can be more than 16ms?

Tags: android, performance

I'm trying to measure render performance of my App, using [Window#addOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window#addOnFrameMetricsAvailableListener(android.view.Window.OnFrameMetricsAvailableListener,%20android.os.Handler)) to get FrameMetrics and collecting timing data within it.

What I can't understand is that why FrameMetrics#DEADLINE can be more than 16ms on a phone with 60FPS display? If a frame render cost more than 16ms, the frame should fail to show in time and the previous frame remains, causing frame loss (janking).

But according to [FrameMetrics doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/FrameMetrics#DEADLINE), DEADLINE:

> Represents the total time in nanoseconds the system allocated for the app to produce its frame. If FrameMetrics.TOTAL_DURATION < FrameMetrics.DEADLINE, the app hit its intended deadline and there was no jank visible to the user.

What I expect is DEADLINE should be less than 16ms on devices with 60FPS display to avoid frame loss or jank, is there something I'm missing? Can a frame cost more than 16ms and doesn't cause frame loss?